# Zend MVC and IIS7 Rewrite

Tags: zend-framework, iis-7, url-rewriting

I've looked everywhere for a couple of days, and apparently I am on the only one on the planet with this problem...

I am using a simple rewrite rule to get requests routed to /public/index.php
This WORKS, but nothing else does... Once the request is routed, my layout can't seem to find anything in terms of classes and includes, so I simply get the layout and where the content should be, I get PAGE NOT FOUND.

When I navigate to www.domain.com/public/index.php - everything works fine. It is only when the rewrite happens that I get the problem.

I have tried all of the "standard" rewrite rules out there. This is the rule I am working with...

rule name="Imported Rule" stopProcessing="true"

match url="^(.*)$"

action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php"

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other annoyance is that it works fine through the debugger (NetBeans xdebug) with no rewrite needed... So, this has me at a dead stop.

Answer (score 0):

I've literally just fixed this in ZF1's SVN trunk. I'd love it if you could test! The issue is [ZF-4491](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4491).

The subversion code is here: http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/